# clothing should be pronounced as /ˈkloʊ.zɪŋ/ or /ˈkloʊ.ðɪŋ/?

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, I checked up some dictionary and found that most dictionaries pronounce "**clothing**" as `/ˈkloʊ.ðɪŋ/`  [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clothing), [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clothing?q=clothing), [M-w](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/clothing)

However, when checking the voice, Cambridge & Oxford seem to pronounce like `/ˈkloʊ.zɪŋ/` while M-w pronounce like `/ˈkloʊ.ðɪŋ/`.

*Seem like `/ð/` is assimilated into `/z/` in this case right?*

Comment: It should be pronounced as /ˈkloʊ.ðɪŋ/. 'z' is way off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need a bit more ear training. The audio on all three sites uses a /ð/ not a /z/. The consonant /ð/ is very often subject to elision in consonant clusters, but won't be elided or change it's place of articulation between vowels. Very often /ð/ is realised as an approximant instead of a fricative in normal speech (so that there is no audible friction), but this is not what is happening in the three audios in the links.